# Assign value from request.get to a const for further Use. Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a utils layer with some functions inside like getUserInfo(userToken). I call this getUserInfo function to get userId. I get Node js works asynchronously,  But is there any way I can achieve the below functionality. I am using npm request library to make rest calls.

1. routes/controller.js receives call with userToken. Make a call to getUserInfo() in utils/users.js to get UserId. getUserInfo function makes a request.get('url', function (e, r, b)) call to external service.

I am trying to implement the following, But Not interested in using callbacks and having nested stuff.

```
//Controller Layer Part
router.get('/api', check, async function (req, res) {
    const userId = await users.getUserInfo(req.headers.authorization);
    const result = await assignmentsService.getAssignments(userId);
    res.send(result);
});

//Utils Layer Part
async function getUserInfo(accessToken, callback){
    const userId = await request.get({
        url: 'someUrl',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': accessToken
            }
        },
        await function (error, response, body){
            const userId = JSON.parse(body).nickname;
        });
    return userId;
}
```

Comment: `As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated`. Why do you still choose to use `request`? Instead you can use built-in [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback) or some other library such as [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

Comment: @jkhvjs request seemed to be simple and easier to use. Any suggestions for such simple to use libraries with the above implementation

Comment: @AnvithReddyCholleti The comment includes some suggestions.

Comment: `request.get()` doesn't return a Promise, you can't use `await`. See https://github.com/request/request#promises--asyncawait

Comment: @Barmar Making sure they fit my scenario? Looking at axios, seems to be a good fit. Any comments?

Comment: No personal experience with them, but Axios seems to be very popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your request. I would recommend [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for you.

Example below:

```js
const axios = require("axios");

//Controller Layer Part
router.get("/api", check, async function (req, res) {
  const userId = await users.getUserInfo(req.headers.authorization);
  const result = await assignmentsService.getAssignments(userId);
  res.send(result);
});

//Utils Layer Part
async function getUserInfo(accessToken) {
  const response = await axios.get("someUrl", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: accessToken,
    },
  });
  console.log(response);
  const userId = JSON.parse(response.data).nickname; //it may not be response.data but you can change.
  return userId;
}
```